# Sidebar not moving to the side

Tags: css, sidebar

Sorry if this question was already asked but I looked at all answers and none helped solving my issue.

I'm new to CSS and I'm trying to move the sidebar to the side but nothing worked.

Could anyone help please?

I tried changing the `float:left and float:right` but it didn't help. I also tried changing or deleting *margins* and *paddings* but in vain.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```css
    /*
    Theme Name: HTML5;
    Date: Feb 2018;
    Description: Learn Basic HTML;
    Version: 0.1;
    Author: MWQ;
    Author URL: www.example.com;
    */
    
    body{
        background-image: url('../img/bodybg.png');
        color: #000305;
        font-size: 90%;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:link, a:visited{color:#e74c3c;}
    a:hover, a:active{color:#f58233;}
    
    .body{
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 70%;
        clear: both;
    }
    
    /* ------- Main Header --------*/
    .mainheader img{
        width: 100%
    }
    
    
    .mainheader nav{
        background-color: #e74c3c;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .mainheader nav ul{
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    .mainheader nav ul li{
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .mainheader a:link, .mainheader a:visited{
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        display: inline-block;
    } 
    
    .mainheader a:hover, .mainheader a:active{
        color: white;
        background-color: #f58233;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    } 
    
    /* ------- Main Content --------*/
    
    .mainContent{
        width: 70%;
        float: left;
    }
    
    .top-content{
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 3%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .post-info{
        font-size: 90%;
        color: #999;
        font-style: italic;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
    
    .post-content{
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .theSidebar{
        width: 22%;
        margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <!----------HEAD--------->
        <head>
            <title>HTML5 CSS3, & Responsive!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
            <meta charset=utf-8>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <!----------Body--------->
    
        <body class="body">
            <header class="mainheader">
                <img src="img/header.jpg"/>
                <nav><ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul></nav>
            </header>
            
            <div class="mainContent"></div>
            <section class="top-content">
                <header></header>
                <h2><a href="#">My Intro Text</a></h2>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Written By: MWQ</p>
                </footer>
                <article>
                    <p>
                        Eram admodum occaecat. Esse 
                        laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum concursionibus commodo velit 
                        doctrina ad sunt ne nostrud an aliqua, tamen admodum quo voluptatibus, consequat 
                        amet ne proident firmissimum te se quo anim nescius id quorum appellat an 
                        laborum.
                    </p>
                </article>
            </section>
            
            <section class="top-content">
                <header></header>
                <h2><a href="#">Video Tutorial</a></h2>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Written By: MWQ</p>
                </footer>
                <article>
                    <p>
                        Eram admodum occaecat. Esse 
                        laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum concursionibus commodo velit 
                        doctrina ad sunt ne nostrud an aliqua, tamen admodum quo voluptatibus, consequat 
                        amet ne proident firmissimum te se quo anim nescius id quorum appellat an 
                        laborum.
                    </p>
                </article>
            </section>
            
                <!----------Side Bar--------->
            <aside>
                <article class="theSidebar">
                <h1> First Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            
            
            <aside>
                <article class="theSidebar">
                <h1> Second Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            
            
            <aside>
                <article class="theSidebar">
                <h1> Third Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            
                <!----------Footer--------->
    
            <footer><p>Copy Rights</p></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hre goes the code:

```css
/*
    Theme Name: HTML5;
    Date: Feb 2018;
    Description: Learn Basic HTML;
    Version: 0.1;
    Author: MWQ;
    Author URL: www.example.com;
    */
    
    body{
        background-image: url('../img/bodybg.png');
        color: #000305;
        font-size: 90%;
        font-family: 'Arial', 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
        line-height: 1.5;
        text-align: left;
    }
    
    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    a:link, a:visited{color:#e74c3c;}
    a:hover, a:active{color:#f58233;}
    
    .body{
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 70%;
        clear: both;
    }
    
    /* ------- Main Header --------*/
    .mainheader img{
        width: 100%
    }
    
    
    .mainheader nav{
        background-color: #e74c3c;
        height: 40px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 999;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .mainheader nav ul{
        text-align: center;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    
    .mainheader nav ul li{
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .mainheader a:link, .mainheader a:visited{
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        display: inline-block;
    } 
    
    .mainheader a:hover, .mainheader a:active{
        color: white;
        background-color: #f58233;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
    } 
    
    /* ------- Main Content --------*/
    
    .mainContent{
        width: 70%;
        position: absolute;
        right: 1px;
    }
    
    .top-content{
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 3%;
        margin-top: 3%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .post-info{
        font-size: 90%;
        color: #999;
        font-style: italic;
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
    
    .post-content{
        display: inline;
    }
    
    .theSidebar{
        width: 22%;
        margin: 2% 0 0 2%;
        float: left;
        padding: 2%;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <!----------HEAD--------->
        <head>
            <title>HTML5 CSS3, & Responsive!</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
            <meta charset=utf-8>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <!----------Body--------->
    
        <body class="body">
            <header class="mainheader">
                <img src="img/header.jpg"/>
                <nav><ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                 </ul></nav>
            </header>
            
            <div class="mainContent">
            <section class="top-content">
                <header></header>
                <h2><a href="#">My Intro Text</a></h2>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Written By: MWQ</p>
                </footer>
                <article>
                    <p>
                        Eram admodum occaecat. Esse 
                        laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum concursionibus commodo velit 
                        doctrina ad sunt ne nostrud an aliqua, tamen admodum quo voluptatibus, consequat 
                        amet ne proident firmissimum te se quo anim nescius id quorum appellat an 
                        laborum.
                    </p>
                </article>
            </section>
            
            <section class="top-content">
                <header></header>
                <h2><a href="#">Video Tutorial</a></h2>
                <footer>
                    <p class="post-info">Written By: MWQ</p>
                </footer>
                <article>
                    <p>
                        Eram admodum occaecat. Esse 
                        laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum concursionibus commodo velit 
                        doctrina ad sunt ne nostrud an aliqua, tamen admodum quo voluptatibus, consequat 
                        amet ne proident firmissimum te se quo anim nescius id quorum appellat an 
                        laborum.
                    </p>
                </article>
            </section>
            </div>
            
                <!----------Side Bar--------->
                <aside class="theSidebar">
            <aside>
                <article>
                <h1> First Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            
            
            <aside>
                <article >
                <h1> Second Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            
            
            <aside>
                <article >
                <h1> Third Side Bar </h1>
                <p>Eram admodum occaecat. Esse laboris expetendis, possumus nam amet ab ipsum oncursionibus commodo velit doctrina.
                </p>
                </article>
            </aside>
            </aside>
            
                <!----------Footer--------->
    
            <footer><p>Copy Rights</p></footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I have made changes to the CSS file, adding the `position` attribute.
If you want to read more about this attribute of CSS, visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp.
Hope it helps...